# Prove that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for any $\epsilon >0$, $\exists v \in U$ with $|x-v| < \epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U = \{ \frac{m\pi}{n} | m \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Prove that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and for any $\varepsilon >0$, $\exists v \in U$ with $|x-v| < \varepsilon$.

I know I am suppose to use the density theorem however I am having a difficult time applying this.  Is it enough to let $v = \frac{m\pi}{n}$ and plug it into $0 < |x-v| < \varepsilon$ and rearrange the inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, there are $m,n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\left|\frac x\pi-\frac mn\right|<\frac\varepsilon\pi$. And therefore $\left|x-\frac{m\pi}n\right|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Carlos Santons Thanks for the answer! I am however a tad confused as to how you were able to show that.

Comment: You apply the denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to the element $\frac{x}{\pi} \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, you just multiply both sides of the inequality by $\pi$.

Comment: @Mark Exactly *what* did I do that confused you?